# maven - Make transitive dependency as default & override direct dependency

Tags: java, maven

Take the 2 dependencies below (A & B) as an example. Dependency B is a parent dependency that normally already includes dependency A but, I also want to define dependency A directly. What I want is for dependency A to default as being included with B but, if I end up excluding B (in some other project) then, dependency A would still be included & instead taken from its direct definement.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.super.duper</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-A</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.super.duper</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-B</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is this scenario possible ? I have tried playing with scopes & position in pom of being defined but, it seems that Dependency A is never included as a child of Dependency B by default.

Comment: If you declare dependency A explicitly, it will definitely be included even if B not present but you would have to provide its version as well.

Comment: @Smile I didn't include this in the code but, I am using a <parent> section that defines default versions for several common libraries. So, what your saying is that there is no way for transitive dependency A to be the default instead of the same explicitly defined dependency A ?

Comment: I suggest updating the question with larger pom snippet (complete if possible) and rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct dependencies override transitive dependencies. That cannot be changed.

But I guess this is not the real problem you want to solve, but you are thinking of a concrete problem. It would probably be better to ask a new question with the concrete problem so that we can find a solution for it.

Comment: I have a concrete case. I have two dependencies : ognl:ognl:3.3.3 and org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.7.2. Thymeleaf depends on ognl:ognl:3.1.26 and my project ends up not working because of Thymeleaf not finding a class in ognl:ognl:3.3.3. Why would Maven not give thymeleaf the version of ognl it specifies ?

Comment: @AdrienH Because you can only have one version of a given JAR on the classpath. Maven needs to choose. The underlying reason is that you cannot load two different classes with the same name in the same JVM (unless you do some classloader magic). So loading two versions of ognl will likely cause chaos because they have overlapping classes and you never know which class is actually called.